# Using a single SQL Trigger to copy multiple rows from a single deletion?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm trying to remove a single row from a table, which can trigger and copy all relative information (multiple rows) to a Third Table. I've constructed a simple example below:

---

**Table: Students**

```
NAME     AGE
-----    ------
Mark     19
Jim      21
Scott    22
```

**Table: Grades**

```
NAME     GRADE
-----    ------
Mark     95
Mark     98
Jim      60
Scott    100
Scott    79
Scott    77
```

**Table: Backup (what I what the Trigger to accomplish)**

```
SQL> DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME='MARK';
SQL> SELECT * FROM BACKUP;

NAME     AGE      GRADE
-----    ------   ------
Mark     19       95
Mark     19       98
```

In the above example, removing the row "Mark...30" would also remove the two rows in the second table with "Mark" as the name. I'm not sure how to do this. I am able to compile the trigger code, but calling "DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME='MARK'" returns a too-many-rows error. Below is my code

**My Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER save_the_grades
BEFORE DELETE
ON grades
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
     v_grade number(3);
BEGIN

SELECT grade INTO v_grade FROM Grades WHERE Names=:old.name;

INSERT INTO backup
(name, age, grade)
VALUES
(:old.name, :old.age, v_grade);
END;
```

Comment: if you are wanting to keep deleted records around, wouldn't a better system be to have a flag on the table row and a view that only returns items that aren't flagged as deleted.

Comment: At the risk of having the wrath of StackOverflow brought down on me, this is related to a homework problem where a Trigger is required. However that problem is far, far larger than this one. I'm only trying to get a feel for how to do it.

Comment: You've tagged this for MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle.  Those are three different databases with three different procedural language extensions and three very different sets of syntax to define triggers.  My guess from the rest of your question is that you are using Oracle so the MySQL and SQL Server tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You get a too many rows because you make a select into which accepts only a result of one row. Try to combine the the Select and the insert

```
INSERT INTO backup
(name, age, grade)
SELECT :old.name, :old.age, grade FROM Grades WHERE Names=:old.name;
```